# Android: Accessing ui elements from thread

Tags: android, android-widget, handler, timertask

```
public Button stb;
static int cnt=0;
public ArrayList<RadioButton> Butgrp1 = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
Timer myt;
TimerTask t;
```

stb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    myt.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            System.out.println("Entering run");
            Handler h=new Handler();

            h.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Butgrp1.get(cnt).setChecked(true);
                            cnt=cnt+1;
                            if(cnt>4)
                                cnt=0;
                            if(cnt>0)
                            //  Butgrp1.get(cnt-1).setChecked(false);
                            System.out.println(cnt);
                        }
                    });


                }
            });

            //rg.getChildAt(cnt).setPressed(true);

        }
    },1000,2000);
```

I need to access a group of radio buttons on the ui and set it as checked at regular intervals, but i keep getting different errors, i realized i must use a handler, but its still not working...can anyone please tell me where i am going wrong....am a newbie and am trying out stuff to understand the working better...please help...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use your own Handler instead of Timer and timed taks.

```
RefreshHandler mHandler = new RefreshHandler();
```

With:

```
class RefreshHandler extends Handler
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        postYourElements();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) 
    {
      this.removeMessages(0);
      sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
 }
```

And than use the function:

```
private void postYourElements()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Butgrp1.get(cnt).setChecked(true);
                            cnt=cnt+1;
                            if(cnt>4)
                                cnt=0;
                            if(cnt>0)
                            //  Butgrp1.get(cnt-1).setChecked(false);
                            System.out.println(cnt);
                        }
                    });
    mHandler.sleep(TimerIntervallInMs);
}
```

To start the Handler just call the `postYourElements()` function under onClick Method.

I'm not sure if this works for you but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

```
youractivityname.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         Butgrp1.get(cnt).setChecked(true);
                        cnt=cnt+1;
                        if(cnt>4)
                            cnt=0;
                        if(cnt>0)
                        //  Butgrp1.get(cnt-1).setChecked(false);
                        System.out.println(cnt);
                    }
                });
```